# Swift 4.1: array in dictionary not updated

Tags: swift4.1

This strange behavior baffles me. I intend to create a dictionary with a single array field. Then within this array, two extra sub dictionaries are appended. Here is code,

```
    var dictionary = [String: Any]()
    var array = [[String: Any]]()
    dictionary["array"] = array

    var dict1:[String:Any] = ["abc": 123, "def": true]
    var dict2:[String:Any] = ["111": 1.2345, "222": "hello"]
    array.append(dict1)
    array.append(dict2)
```

[Debugger output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KnvDW.png).

[image]

As you can see from the debugger output, the var array is updated successfully (with 2 sub dictionaries appended). But the `dictionary["array"]` still has 0 value.

It appears the (`dictionary["array"]`) and (`array`) are two separate objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, they are separate. The element `dictionary["array"]` is an immutable value of type `Array<_>` because it's added as a value type to the dictionary not a reference type.

If you tried to add `dict1` to the array by addressing the element via it's encapsulating dictionary like this:

```
(dictionary["array"] as! Array).append(dict1)
```

You would see an error like this:

```
error: cannot use mutating member on immutable value of type 'Array<_>'
```

From the [Swift Language docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ClassesAndStructures.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH13-ID88), emphasis added:

> A value type is a type whose value is copied when it is assigned to a variable or constant, or when it is passed to a function.
>
> You’ve actually been using value types extensively throughout the previous chapters. In fact, all of the basic types in Swift—integers, floating-point numbers, Booleans, strings, **arrays and dictionaries**—are value types, and are implemented as structures behind the scenes.